# Next page link shows same posts Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

When I click next page, it goes to the next page (at least in the url it shows "www.url.com/?s=et&paged=2"), but it shows the same posts. What is wrong with my search?

search.php

http://pastebin.com/VXkpKqAS

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `paged` in the URL, but your code is looking for `$_GET['page']`